# How to set default-cascade in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I find we can specify the "default-cascade" attribute of the  element. But how can I do it in Fluent NHibernate? And I don't want to use AutoMapping.

Comment: I mean to set the DEFAULT casacade behavior in one point! not in every Map class. And the setting in the Map class can override the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detailed description could be found here: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions. An extract:

> There are some situations that are so obvious that they just cried out for a simple shortcut that can be applied globally to your project:

```
Table.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name + "Table")
...
DefaultCascade.All()
...
```

And this way we can use it:

```
Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(/* database config */)
  .Mappings(m =>
  {
    m.FluentMappings
      .AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity>()
      .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All());
  })
```

Also check this, to get some idea how to implement own **Conventions** [Fluent NHibernate automapping and cascading](https://mookid.dk/2009/09/27/fluent-nhibernate-automapping-and-cascading/)

Comment: Thanks very much! That's what I want.